# How to compare the count of unique values

Tags: r, compare

I need to check whether the number of elements of each unique value in the variable PPT in A is equal to the number of elements of each unique value in PPT in B, and whether there is any value unique only to A or only to B.

For example:

```
PPTa <- c("ppt0100109","ppt0301104","ppt0100109","ppt0100109","ppt0300249","ppt0100109","ppt0300249","ppt0100109","ppt0504409","ppt2303401","ppt0704210","ppt0704210","ppt0100109")
CNa <- c(110,54,110,110,49,10,49,110,409,40,10,10,110)
LLa <- c(150,55,150,150,45,15,45,115,405,45,5,15,50)
A <-data.frame(PPTa,CNa,LLa)

PPTb <- c("ppt0100200","ppt0300249","ppt0100109","ppt0300249","ppt0100109","ppt0764091","ppt2303401","ppt0704210","ppt0704210","ppt0100109")
CNb <- c(110,54,110,110,49,10,49,110,409,40)
LLb <- c(150,55,150,150,45,15,45,115,405,45)
B <-data.frame(PPTb,CNb,LLb)
```

In this case, we have these unique values which occur a certain amount of times:

```
A$PPTa       TIMES
"ppt0100109" 6
"ppt0301104" 1
"ppt0300249" 2
"ppt0504409" 1
"ppt2303401" 1
"ppt0704210" 2

B$PPTb       TIMES
"ppt0100200" 1
"ppt0300249" 2
"ppt0100109" 3
"ppt0764091" 1
"ppt2303401" 1
"ppt0704210" 2
```

I would like to create a new matrix (or anything you could suggest) with a value of 0 if the unique value exists both in A and B with the same number of elements, a value of 1 if it exists in both dataframes A and B but the number of elements differ, and a value of 2 if the value exists only in one of the two dataframes.
Something like:

```
A$PPTa       TIMES  OUTPUT
"ppt0100109" 6      1
"ppt0301104" 1      2
"ppt0300249" 2      0
"ppt0504409" 1      2
"ppt2303401" 1      0
"ppt0704210" 2      0

B$PPTb       TIMES  OUTPUT
"ppt0100200" 1      2
"ppt0300249" 2      0
"ppt0100109" 3      1
"ppt0764091" 1      2
"ppt2303401" 1      0
"ppt0704210" 2      0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested `ifelse` statement,

```
ifelse(do.call(paste0, A) %in% do.call(paste0, B), 0, ifelse(A$PPTa %in% B$PPTb, 1, 2))
#[1] 1 0 2 2 0 0
 ifelse(do.call(paste0, B) %in% do.call(paste0, A), 0, ifelse(B$PPTb %in% A$PPTa, 1, 2))
#[1] 1 2 0 0 2 0
```